# Can't resolve font path using styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to include a google font **Epilogue** to my project using `@font-face` and `styled-components`. I created `GlobalStyle.style.js`at the `/src` folder and imported it to my `App.js`. I seem to be doing something wrong with the `@font-face` because I keep getting this error on my browser:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/GlobalStyle.style.js 4:0-57

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/fonts/Epilogue-Medium.tff' in 'D:\projects\React\Styled components\styled-components\src'


ERROR in ./src/GlobalStyle.style.js 5:0-55

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/fonts/Epilogue-Bold.tff' in 'D:\projects\React\Styled components\styled-components\src'
```

My `GlobalStyle.style.js` has

```
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"
import Font500 from "./assets/fonts/Epilogue-Medium.tff"
import Font700 from "./assets/fonts/Epilogue-Bold.tff"

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle `

    @font-face {
        font-family: Epilogue-500;
        src: url(${Font500}) format('tff');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Epilogue-700;
        src: url(${Font700}) format('tff');
    }
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Epilogue-700;
        font-size: 1.125rem;
    }

`

export const MainContainer = styled.div `
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
`

export default GlobalStyle
```

My `App.js`

```
import GlobalStyle from "./GlobalStyle.style"
import { MainContainer } from "./GlobalStyle.style"

function App() {
  return (
    <MainContainer >
      <GlobalStyle />
      <p>This should have the Epilogue font</p>
    </MainContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `<p>` should have the Epilogue font

Answer (score 1):

In your case it would be awesome if you could share a code sandbox or smth similar.

According to your description the font would need to be at
`src/assets/fonts/Epilogue-Medium.tff`
is that the case?

If they are not, thats the reason. If they already are there maybe it helps to try to use absolut paths like

`import Font700 from "src/assets/fonts/Epilogue-Bold.tff"`

Comment: I double checked the fonts as suggested and also included the absolute path. I then realised the font format I set to `tff` instead of `ttf`. It worked after fixing the typo.